# HIVE table create and select success, but next query says table does not exist

Tags: hive, azure-hdinsight

I have create an external table and verified the data is there with 'show table extended like tablename'. I am attempting to create a 2nd table with a select from the first table that uses variables to do a little math:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sampletable 

set pi = 3.1415926

create table sampletable as
select
*
, somecolumn/${hiveconf:pi}  as someothercolumn
from someothertable
limit 1000
```

The job returns a success, but when I run this job:

```
select * from sampletable
```

I get:

FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:15 Table not found 'sampletable'

Comment: Is the query without "create table ... as" returning any values?

Comment: can you describe the sampletable and check....

Comment: I think it was related to a location path issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580097/not-a-file-exception-on-select-after-successful-insert